# how do I recover file of k8s job

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say some time ago we created a kubernetes job with

```
kubectl apply -f FILE.yaml
```

but in a few month we lost the FILE.yaml 
how can we get the FILE.yaml from **kubectl**?

I have tried commands such as

```
kubectl get pod JOBNAME -o yaml > FILE_RECOVERED.yaml
```

but this is not the result that I expect. I want FILE_RECOVERED.yaml == FILE.yaml

Comment: If you want a file that's bit-for-bit identical to what you originally submitted to the cluster, Kubernetes doesn't keep track of that.  Check the file into source control instead.

Comment: Hi, @DavidMaze what do you mean by source control here? For me it is not obvious how to turn FILE_RECOVERED.yaml  into FILE.yaml. I guess some people might solve this already.

Comment: Before you run `kubectl apply` the first time, use `git add && git commit` or another similar tool to record what you've deployed to the cluster.

Comment: I hope there should be a better solution solely by resources of k8s :)